# Property not found in web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

The Result property in actionExecutedContext.Result cannot be resolved. Any ideas why?
Here's my code.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using System.Net.Http;

public class ValidateFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var modelState = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ModelState;
        if (!modelState.IsValid)
        {
            var errors = modelState
                .Where(s => s.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                .Select(s => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(s.Key, s.Value.Errors.First().ErrorMessage))
                .ToArray();

            actionExecutedContext.Result = new HttpResponseMessage<KeyValuePair<string, string>[]>(errors, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the beta days of Web API, `HttpActionExecutedContext` hasn't had a `Result` property but a `Response` property instead.

You can assign the `HttpResponseMessage` instance to it.

See the framework [source code here](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Filters/HttpActionExecutedContext.cs#L46).